# jQuery selectize doesn't store react hooks state

Tags: jquery, reactjs, react-hooks, selectize.js

I am having problem implementing dropdown menu using selectize, so i tried jquery along with react, every thing was going great until... my state (that previously was being stored without jquery) isn't being stored now using jquery, no matter what i do.

**Entire Function Component**

```
const Home: React.FC = () => {
  const [something, setSomething] = useState(10);
  const getVal = (data: any) => {
    let curVal = currencyxvalue.get(data);
    return setSomethingHandler(curVal);
  };
  const setSomethingHandler = (vars: any) => {
    if (vars !== null) {
      console.log("bssn : ", vars);
      return setSomething(vars);
    }
  };
  console.log(currencyxvalue.keys());
  $(document).ready(() => {
    $("select").selectize({
      sortField: "text",
      onChange: (data) => {
        return getVal(data);
      },
    });
  });
  return (
    <IonPage>
      <IonContent class="tool-bg-2">
        <IonToolbar>
          <select
            id="select"
            placeholder="Crypto Currency"
            draggable={false}
            className="height-adjust"
          >
            {currency_list.map((cur) => (
              <option key={currency_list.indexOf(cur)} value={cur}>
                {cur}
              </option>
            ))}
          </select>
        </IonToolbar>
      </IonContent>
      <IonContent>values of currency : {something}</IonContent>
    </IonPage>
  );
};
```

it basically is a dropdown menu, now the problem is that, using onchange the value goes to setSomethingHandler function smoothly, without any problem.But when it goes to the setSomething function which should set the value of Something, the value is not being set or being constantly reset.

I have tried enough approaches but to keep it short, this is the exact problem.
Anyone who can help me out?

Comment: Perhaps something is lost in translation here, React hooks don't have state, components do. Can you share your component code that is using the state hooks and jquery function? Also, generally speaking, jquery and React don't play well together since they have pretty orthogonal approaches to UI, jquery direct manipulation of the DOM and React working in a VirtualDOM with state and props.

Comment: I have edited the question can you please check now?

Comment: You should consider using the react alternative of selectize (https://github.com/furqanZafar/react-selectize - or any other select library that exist in react) and dropping the use of jQuery inside your project.

Comment: Sorry, I meant *the entire* component, so we can see its state and any function that effect  the state and what's rendered. Just about everything devs try to do with jquery within React can be done/accomplished in a React-y way.

Comment: i have uploaded entire component, if you also want a working code i can provide it to you :)

Comment: @DrewReese i also tried this above code without return statements in fucntions as only calling setSomething is necessary, but it also didn't work.

Comment: The selectize behavior aside, the `onChange` handler should typically be attached to the `select` element directly. I tagged `selectize.js` so hopefully someone with specific experience can help. Can you go ahead and provide working code, in a *running* codesandbox or similar? While it's recommended to not mix jquery and React it's not impossible to get them to work together.

Comment: It doesnt work along with selectize, but alone without the jquery document, it does.